# TypeScript: Optional params in Class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a moderately big class with a lot of different attributes. Since there are a lot of them, making a constructor for the class would be pretty clumsy (imagine having new CLassObj(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6, par7, ...pars) in your code. It'd be impossible to remember the order, so I usually initialize it like this:

```
{
    movie: this.movie,
    row: 10,
    seat: 12,
    cashPrice: 170,
    discount: 0,
    bonusesPrice: 4200,
    is3D: false,
    isVR: false,
    includesGlasses: false,
    promocode: ''
  }
```

and that's okay. But If I have a method inside the class, then I'd need to redefine it too!

Is there any way to make optional params without making a constructor? Or is there a sane way of making constructor take the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Partial<T>` as parameter to the constructor. This allows for an object literal that optionally specifies any member of the class:

```
class BigClass {
    movie: string;
    row: number;
    seat:number;
    cashPrice: number;
    discount: number;
    bonusesPrice: number;
    is3D: boolean;
    isVR: boolean;
    includesGlasses: boolean;
    promocode: string;
    public constructor (cfg: Partial<BigClass>){
        Object.assign(this, cfg);
    }
    method (){

    }
}

var d = new BigClass({
    is3D: true
});
```

Comment: This stuff really helped me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to create a class with optional parameters :

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public id?: string,
    public fullName?: string,
  ) {}
}
```

you can now call it with

```
let user = new User();
let user = new User('ID1');
let user = {};
let user = { id: 'ID1' }; // Your IDE will give you completion in that case
// And so on ...
```

Comment: And this is a full class BTW, meaning you don't have to declare your properties, they're implicitly declared in the constructor

Comment: The problem is see is that you still have to specify the parameters in order, and you can't initialize easily with an object literal if you have methods (which the question says is part of the problem)

Comment: Well since you don't use the constructor, my guess was that you didn't care about the order, just how you can declare objects that match the class ... And I agree, you will have to declare methods. But maybe you could get the methods out of the class, and create an utils class for them ?

Comment: Not my question, just an opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few solutions to this problem.

You could use deconstructing: [C:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BarConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20z%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20z%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%7B%20x%2C%20y%2C%20z%20%7D%3A%20BarConstructor)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.z%20%3D%20z%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

You could use some design patterns like builder: [C:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20z%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FooBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20instance%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20%3CFoo%3E%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setX(x%3A%20number)%3A%20FooBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.instance.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setY(y%3A%20number)%3A%20FooBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.instance.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setZ(z%3A%20number)%3A%20FooBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.instance.z%20%3D%20z%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20build()%3A%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20new%20FooBuilder()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.setX(1)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.setY(2)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.setZ(3)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.build()%0D%0A)